# How to use python selenium to select value in React-Select Component dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

[very new at selenium and HTML]

I want to select a drop down from a website. The `type` is hidden. I just want to pass or select either `male` or `female` from the drop down or pass it into the `value` variable, how would I do this?

I used the inspect element in chrome to determine the two lines below are the ones required to select a value.

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="female">
```

I got the xpath from chrome and tried to pass a value but did not work:

```
gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[2]/div/input")
gender.send_keys('male')
```

The entire HTML of the above `div` element is:

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="female">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-value">
                <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-5--value-item">Female</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" 
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value">
            <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
            <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

edit:

HTML from where I click on the drop down without any values selected:

```
<div class="Select is-searchable Select--single">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-placeholder">Select:</div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false"
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; 
                            overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; 
                            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; 
                            font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit2:

HTML from value selected in drop down

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="male">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-value">
                <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-5--value-item">Male</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" 
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; 
                            overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; 
                            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; 
                            font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value">
            <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent sibling/DOM:

```
<div class="col-md-2"><div class="form-input  form-group"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span><label for="customer.in_state" class="control-label">In-State</label><span class="input-group"><div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"><input name="customer.in_state" type="hidden" value="1"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-11--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-11--value-item">In-State</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input aria-activedescendant="react-select-11--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span><span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `execute_script('javascript.find.input.="Male"')`?

Comment: @MosheSlavin I have not tried that. Can I run that in python? or how would I run it in selenium can you show me an example please?

Comment: I am not an expert in JS but you definitely can do that!

Comment: @RustyShackleford , Note, that if you want your script to simulate user-like behavior, then you should NOT use `execute_script` to handle elements on page. Instead write lines that will perform exactly the same actions as you do as user. So if you need to select value from drop-down menu: click on drop-down to expand it -> wait for option to be visible(clickable) -> click on option

Comment: @Andersson I am trying to go for what you said, but I am not able to pick up the exact lines in the HTML that take me to the drop down

Comment: @RustyShackleford , what is the sequence of actions you need to execute? On which line you got an exception/which exception?

Comment: @Andersson the sequence is that I want to click the drop down and select either male or female from the drop down options.

Comment: @RustyShackleford , so I guess the first line should be click on `<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">` element, right? Did you try it?

Comment: @Andersson just tried it like this, not sure if correct `gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<div class='Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single'>")
`

Comment: @RustyShackleford , try `driver.find_element_by_class_name("Select").click()` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.Select.has-value").click()`...

Comment: @Andersson this worked!(didnt see any results but the line runs): `gender = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.Select.has-value").click()
`

Comment: @Andersson when I restarted my browswer and script I got this error at the drop down from your response:

`
WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">...</div> is not clickable at point (728, 369). Other element would receive the click: <td data-value="..." class="rdtDay rdtToday">18</td>`

Comment: @RustyShackleford , try to do all imports as [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clockable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Select.has-value"))).click()`

Comment: @Andersson getting this error now `WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">...</div> is not clickable at point (728, 369). Other element would receive the click: <td data-value="..." class="rdtDay rdtToday">18</td>`

I think since there are multiple dropdowns on the page the driver is getting confused. What do you think?

Comment: @RustyShackleford , do you see something that really might cover drop-down? Is there some element tthat is visible when you navigate to page and disappeared after some time? Share URL if it's a public web-page

Comment: @Andersson that is exactly what is happening, there are elements that appear when drop down is selected and disappers when otherwise not selected. Unfortunately page is not public, and contains HIPPA material

Comment: @RustyShackleford it's hard to solve your issue without understanding how does the page looks like, what's happening when you enters the page and what exactly you should do to select the option...

Comment: @Andersson I put the html above where I selected a value from the drop down. Will that not helP/

Comment: Just share me what is the parent dom or preceding sibiling of this div <div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"> ? You have any label tag preceding this? That can help me to give you right solution

Comment: @Navarasu sorry for the delay had some work issues come up. I added the preceding sibling of the div class. Do you think that is correct/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page uses [React Select Component](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). As other discussed in the group, You have to automate this case exactly similar like the manual steps,

*i.e.,*

1. *Click the element which is intractable.*
2. *Wait for the dropdown appears.*
3. *Click the value from the dropdown.*

You have two case here,

- Select with when no value
- select when there is value.

I assume that page has single select box similar to that and gender value is not selected by default. In below code,I am selecting male case. After selecting male, I am changing it to Female.

**Seleting the dropdown without value**

```
# this is click the div..Select-placeholder element which is intractable

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Select--single .Select-placeholder').click()

# Then we are waiting for the dropdown value to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
male= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Select-option#react-select-5--option-0)')))

# Click the element male option value of the dropdown
male.click()
```

**Seleting the dropdown with value**

```
# this is click the div.Select-value element which is intractable
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Select--single .Select-value').click()
female = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Select-option#react-select-5--option-1)')))

# Click the element female option value of the dropdown
female.click()
```

**Get selected value**

```
 selected_value=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Select--single .Select-value').text
 print(selected_value)
```

**Clear selected value**

```
 selected_value=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Select--single Select-clear').click()
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do anything. Why are you not calling the `.click()` attributes on the react-select elements?

Comment: It is a typo. Updated it. I have shared only the concept of handling the component. You should not except the exact code here.  Maybe on the component side, the dom structure may be changed. Please check and update the code as per your UI.

Comment: Thanks. Works great now.