# How to uniquely identify react js IDs within Xpath for multiple drop downs python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, dropdownbox

[very new to selenium]

I am using python selenium to click drop downs on a webpage. I can successfully do this using xpath. All the drop downs I want to click are exactly like that ofcourse with the number changing for each of them after the `select`:

```
gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-select-7--value"]/div[2]/input')
gender.send_keys('Male')
gender.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
gender.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
gender.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

How can I unique identify the `react-select-20--value` to click on the drop down ?

Below is the html from the 'highest' `div` class that encapsulates the `react-select-20--value` I want to click here, in this `Gender`.

Other drop downs have a similar structure too.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-input  form-group has-error">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
    <label for="customer.gender" class="control-label">Patient Gender</label>
    <span class="input-group">
    <div class="Select is-searchable Select--single">
    <div class="Select-control">
    <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-20--value">
    <div class="Select-placeholder">Select:</div>
    <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-20--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
    <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block">Select Gender</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit: this is not duplicate question because I can select the drop down but can not select the drop down when the link ID changes.

Comment: can you share the link of the webpage from where you are downloading data if it is a public website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python selenium to select value in React-Select Component dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875653/how-to-use-python-selenium-to-select-value-in-react-select-component-dropdown)

Comment: @thebadguy I can not because it is a private page with HIPAA data

Comment: @Navarasu not duplicate, I can use and select the drop down but not identify it uniquely.